# JavaScript image processing without canvas

Tags: javascript, angular, image-processing, canvas

I am working with Angular 8 and I getting couple of png base64 images from the server via web socket (signalR streaming). More precise: I am getting 15 responses (15 frames) per second and every response has 3 new images.

I need to process those images and present them to the user (currently in canvas).

What I do so far:

```
const image = new Image();
image.onload = () => {

    this.canvasForConversionContext.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);
    const imageData = this.canvasForConversionContext.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);

    // loop trought the image and change color (it can be done in web worker (separate threed))
    this.processImagePixelByPixel(imageData.data);

    // back to canvas to convert processed image data to new image
    this.canvasForConversionContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    const finalImage = new Image();
    finalImage.onload = () => {
      // here are get the final image
    };
    finalImage.src = this.canvasForConversion.toDataURL();

};
image.src = imageFromTheServerInBase64Format;
```

[image]

This simple chart present process.

Those steps below are explanation of the code above:

1. load image gained from server into the image tag
2. put image into canvas for conversion
3. get image data from canvas
4. process image data pixel by pixel
5. put data again into canvas
6. export data from canvas as base64 image
7. create final image from exported base64 image

This is something already done and it works, but it works really slow.
Any other technique or suggestion into the current code how I can speed up this process ?

I tried to avoid canvas to manipulate with the image data, but I did not find anything about that.
There must be something else for manipulation of the image pixel except canvas (some library) ?

Comment: If you are processing photos on the server why not use [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) ? It will run much faster!

Comment: Server is not the option. There are already to much work on the server. It have to be done on the client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problems changing couple things here:

1. We do not need last 2 steps (6 and 7) from the list above:

   > 5. export data from canvas as base64 image
   > 6. create final image from exported base64 image

Since we add data again into the final canvas, we can send current canvas with processed image, since canvas can accept another canvas to add as image inside.

2. We separate streaming process and processing data to another working thread (web worker) and sending already prepared data to main thread.
   Also very important part is that we send data to main thread only if main thread is ready since we do not want to overflow main thread with bunch of data. Main thread became really slow if we send him data which cannot process. In meanwhile in the streaming thread we put all processed data into queue until main thread does not send notification that it is ready and wants more data.
   How to set up signalR streaming to another thread you can find here: [Is it possible to create signalR streaming connection in web worker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952085/is-it-possible-to-create-signalr-streaming-connection-in-web-worker)
3. We changed image data gained from the server from base64 image to array of lines. For example: [3, 5, 34, 3, 6, 34, 3, 7, 35] where every 3 values present [x, y, line length].

   Data gained from the server in this format are smaller and much easier to process since we do not need to load image into the canvas to get pixel data, we immidetly can create image data and process them.

With those 3 steps of improvement we achieved needed performances.